# Read Cookies in SAP Gateway Methods

Tags: cookies, odata, abap, sap-gateway

when implementing a SAP Gateway Service (using DPC_EXT Classes), I'd like to access some custom cookies.

But I dont seem to be able to access them...

Using following code

```
lo_faqcade = /iwbep/if_mgw_conv_srv_runtime~get_dp_facade( ).
lo_facade->get_request_header( ).
```

I get all the HTTP Request headers (**Except** the Cookie Header, which always seems to be empty here)

Comment: If the data contained in the cookie was in the backend, I’d get it from there ;)

Comment: PS: please don’t start the discussion why I a cookie is being used. A custom header is not an option either. The question is how to get hands on the cookie inside the request processing layer.

Comment: not sure but did you see that 2 methods exists from facade class /IWBEP/CL_MGW_DP_FACADE? /IWBEP/IF_MGW_DP_FACADE~GET_REQUEST_HEADER (returns a list of all request headers of the current request) and /IWBEP/IF_MGW_DP_INT_FACADE~GET_REQUEST_HEADER (returns the request header of current service call) ... might "all request" headers solve your issue?

Comment: I did try one of the two (see original post) but not sure which of the two interfaces is hidden behind the get_dp_facade call. Will certainly try that. Thx!

Comment: did it help solving your issue?

Comment: I didnt have a chance yet to try, as other things got prioritized. But this will be get to be a topic in very near future again. Will update here.

Comment: Dumb question maybe ... but isn't it up to the _client_ to add the cookie to the request header? Is the client actually doing that?

Comment: @Florian the cookie is sent. But disappears somewhere between outer icf layer and the GW service implementation layer

Comment: Checked today - BOTH methods return same table. The cookie line is in the list but is empty